# PIC 16F1788 reading voltages

Tags: c, pic, microprocessors

I am a new to PIC programming and need some advice on whether or not I am on the right track with my code. I am writing a function that reads the input values (0-5V) from port 7 and returns a voltage value based from (0-6.5V).

Here is what I have so far:

```
float measure(void) {

    do {
        ADCON1= 0x00; // configure ports as AD
        buffer.vol = ADC_Read(7); // reads value from port 7
        Real = (buffer.vol/5)*6.5; // converts it to voltage between 0 -6.5v
    } while(1);
}
```

Does this look correct?  Do I need to change anything?

Comment: Once a post is answered, please do not delete 90% of it.  Leave it so others may benefit.

Comment: sam brosteain, this is the 2nd time your post has been rolled back after you have deleted a large portion of it.  Please leave a comment if you are trying to do something other than obscuring your own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to reconfigure the pin inside the loop. Start-up configuration should occur at the beginning of `main`.

[`ADC_Read`](http://www.mikroe.com/download/eng/documents/compilers/mikroc/pro/pic/help/adc_library.htm) does not return a floating-point value; you need to convert it yourself. For a 12-bit ADC, you can have

```
const float conversion_factor = 6.5f / ( ( 1 << 12 ) - 1 );
```

and then do

```
Real = ADC_Read(7) * conversion_factor;
```

It's not clear what `buffer` is for. Unless you need to save the unscaled voltage for some reason, don't.

Comment: I have a question it you dont mind is the (1<<12) because there is 12 different I/O ports in the pic? thank you

Comment: the (1<<12) is because it is a 12-bit ADC.